# Just need a little guidance with override and Compare to

Tags: java

So i am unsure what my output should be because I am running into a snag. I know I should be using Override somewhere. I tried it in my cirlce1 class for findPerimeter. Won't work there. There are 3 parts

First is this GeometricObject1 abstract class.

```
abstract class GeometricObject1 {

protected String color;
protected double weight;

    // Default construct  
protected GeometricObject1() {     
        color = "white";
         weight = 1.0; 
    }


    // Construct a geometric object
protected GeometricObject1(String color, double weight) {     
    this.color = color;     
    this.weight = weight;   
} 



// Getter method for color   
public String getColor() {     
    return color;   

} 

// Setter method for color 
public void setColor(String color) {    
    this.color = color;   
} 

// Getter method for weight
public double getWeight() {     
    return weight;   
} //getWeight

// Setter method for weight   
 public void setWeight(double weight) {     
    this.weight = weight;   
} //setWeight


//Write code here for Abstract method for area
public abstract double getArea(); 


//Write code here Abstract method for perimeter

public abstract double getPerimeter();

}
```

next is Circle1 class. I know I need to fill out a few more bodies of code, but I am a bit lost ( I am on the internet and using my book) on how to format a compareto block.

```
class Circle1 extends GeometricObject1 implements Comparable {
protected double radius;
final double pi = Math.PI;

    // Default constructor   
public Circle1() {     
    this(1.0, "white", 1.0);
}   

    // Construct circle with specified radius 
public Circle1(double radius) {     
    super("white", 1.0);
    this.radius = radius;
}

    // Construct a circle with specified radius, weight, and color
public Circle1(double radius, String color, double weight) {     
super(color, weight);
     this.radius = radius;   
} 

    // Getter method for radius
public double getRadius() {     
    return radius;
}    
    // Setter method for radius
public void setRadius(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}   
    // Implement the findArea method defined in GeometricObject   
public double findArea() { 
return pi * Math.pow(radius, 2);   
// Write your code here   
} 

    // Implement the findPerimeter method defined in GeometricObject

public double findPerimeter() { 
return 2 * pi * radius;   

} 
    // Override the equals() method defined in the Object class
public boolean equals(Circle1 circle) {    
// Write your code here 
} 
    // Override the toString() method defined in the Object class
public String toString() {    
// Write your code here   
} 
    // Implement the compareTo method defined in Comparable   
public int compareTo(Object o) { 
    // Write your code here   
} 
public static Circle1 max(Comparable o1, Comparable o2) {    
// Write your code here   
    }
}
```

The last part is my testcircle class and 2/3 compile fine. It is my Circle1 class that is giving me trouble.

Circle1.java:1: error: Circle1 is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPerimeter() in GeometricObject1
is the error I get when i compile my circle1 class

```
public class TestCircle1 {   
// Main method   
    public static void main(String[] args) {     
// Create two comparable circles     
Circle1 circle1 = new Circle1(5);    
Circle1 circle2 = new Circle1(4); 


    // Display the max circle    
    Circle1 circle = Circle1.max(circle1, circle2);
    System.out.println("The max circle's radius is " + circle.getRadius());    
    System.out.println(circle);    
    System.out.println(circle.equals(new Circle1(5))); 

  } 
}
```

Comment: `@Override 
 public double findPerimeter() { 
  return 2 * pi * radius;   

  }`

Comment: Circle1.java:37: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype. is the error i get

Answer (score 0):

You must override `getPerimeter()` and `getArea()` in Circle1 class.

Did you mistype `getPerimeter()` as `findPerimeter()` ? Because `getPerimeter()` function must be overridden.

Comment: You know, I was thinking that. I actually got that findPerimeter from my instructor.
I was wondering, is that a real constructor? Referring to find. ( I am really new to programming, so am i right in calling that a constructor? ha)

Comment: Constructor has the same name as the class. Do you have a findPerimeter Class ? If not then it's not a constructor just a method. In any case, override the 2 methods I told you and your compiler error should vanish.

Comment: it does. I think it was supposed to get getPerimeter and getArea. I don't think there is a find method? A classmate and I are on discord now talking about that find method and were completely confused by it. It did, but I am getting other errors now because I had to add some substance to my compareto and equals code bodies

Comment: public int compareTo(Object o) { 
  if(getArea() > o.getArea())
      return 1;
  else if (getArea() < o.getArea())
      return -1;
  else
      return 0;

error on that.

Comment: if(circle1 == circle2)
      return true;
   else 
      return false;
error on this as well

Comment: Could you post the exact error ? Its hard to say what the error could be

Comment: .Circle1.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
  else if (getArea() < o.getArea())
                        ^
  symbol:   method getArea()
  location: variable o of type Object.. the thing is getArea is in this class, but it can't find it?

Comment: typecast o to Circle1 first. o is of object class.  This is how you typecast : (Circle1) o

Comment: Also your equals method is wrong. It should take argument of type Object. You would then typecast it to Circle1. Read this article for understanding how to override equals : https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~eaugusti/archive/102-winter16/misc/howToOverrideEquals.html

Comment: Anyway, whichever answer on your post solves your problem mark it as accepted/upvote it, so that this problem can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define undefined abstract class methods in your inheriting class. in your case `public double getArea()` and `public double getPerimeter()`.

```
    class Circle1 extends GeometricObject1 implements Comparable {
        protected double radius;
        final double pi = Math.PI;

        // Default constructor   
        public Circle1() {     
            this(1.0, "white", 1.0);
        }   

        // Construct circle with specified radius 
        public Circle1(double radius) {     
            super("white", 1.0);
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        // Construct a circle with specified radius, weight, and color
        public Circle1(double radius, String color, double weight) {     
            super(color, weight);
            this.radius = radius;   
        } 

        // Getter method for radius
        public double getRadius() {     
            return radius;
        }    
        // Setter method for radius
        public void setRadius(double radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }   

        // Override the equals() method defined in the Object class
        public boolean equals(Circle1 circle) {    
            // Write your code here 
            return false;
        } 
        // Override the toString() method defined in the Object class
        public String toString() {    
            // Write your code here   
            return "";
        } 
        // Implement the compareTo method defined in Comparable   
        public int compareTo(Object o) { 
            // Write your code here   
            return 0;

        } 
        public static Circle1 max(Comparable o1, Comparable o2) {    
            // Write your code here   
            return o1.compareTo(o2) < 0 ? (Circle1) o2 : (Circle1) o1;
        }

        @Override
        public double getArea() {
            return pi * Math.pow(radius, 2); 
        }

        @Override
        public double getPerimeter() {
            return 2 * pi * radius;  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will study this and understand it. I was honestly wondering the whole time if i should just switch the find's to get because find just didn't seem right to me. In all these pages I have read in my textbook I have not seen a findsomething